# Do less than and greater than need escaped in a C# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Do `<` and `>` need escaped in a C# regex? I'm uncertain because of named groups and because [this regex cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) has them listed in the metacharacters section.

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "(<body.*?>)", replacement);
```

or

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "(\<body.*?\>)", replacement);
```

Comment: Whatever works, it's that. Besides, do not parse HTML with regexes. Use HTML parsers.

Comment: Btw: if you did need to escape the `<` and `>`, you'd need to use a verbatim string literal:`@"(\<body.*?\>)"` - not `"(\<body.*?\>)"` (or, alternatively, you'd need to use two backslashes instead of one).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is never necessary to escape `<` or `>` in regexen. The only context in which they have a special meaning is if the `<` comes after `(?`. And since regular characters aren't allowed directly after `(?` escaping the `<` there would make no sense (i.e. `(?\<blabla\>)` would be ill-formed).

If you want to match the literal sequence `?<bla>`, you'd need to escape the `?`, not the `<` and in all other cases `<` and `>` have no special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression they will not need escaped because they are not wrapped around a **word**. If your expression was something more like `(?<body>.*?)` then what it would do is capture `.*?` and name it `body`.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't it have to be `(?<body>.*?)`--the `?` starts a special mode in the Regex. So the Regex presented would match any character 0..n times, except `\n` and name the capture `body`.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight, it looks like that is 100% correct, thanks!

Comment: Pesky `?`'s can get troublesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's not strictly necessary, but it sure is clear what you mean if you do escape, whereas not escaping might raise doubts about meaning when you review your code 6 months from now, or when someone else reads it.

Comment: Can you provide a case where it *is* strictly necessary?

Comment: In the case, as Michael Perrenoud points out, where you want to specify a name for a match, where you would use < and > around the name before specifying the pattern. If you would say `<name>\w+` then you would capture `\w+` and name it "name". If you use < in combination with = or !, you create lookbehind expressions.